# Victort Chart - Axis extra tick

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts, victory-native

How are the ticks made in the area indicated by the red arrow in the picture?

Data = [0,10,20,30, ..n]

Short description: Adding extra ticks between 0-10 or 10-20 or 20-30

[image]

Docs not found axis ticks.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question with no tags. Your post should contain code.